# Will Powerline adapters help me to overcome gaming lag when other people are streaming video?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, powerline-networking

People in my household love watching Hulu and Amazon streaming video. The internet works if one person is watching but as soon as two do it goes to crap. Meanwhile, it shoots up my ping to 500 + as soon as someone starts watching in CS:GO.

I can't be wired to the modem due to the house configuration.

My computer (a desktop) is connected through wireless right now. Would a powerline adapter help to reduce my gaming lag?

Do note that I have the "Performance" tier internet from Comcast and at this time it is not my interest to upgrade it, as I don't know whether or not the videos will suck up even more bandwidth.

Help is appreciated, and if you have any questions just leave a comment.

Thank you.

Comment: No;  Your connection only has so much downstream/upstream it can provide.  You being connected to your connection over Powerline, won't change that fact, your ping isn't high because of streaming though.  Case in point, you can have a slow downstream connection, but with very little latency.

Comment: @Ramhound What is causing the ping then if it is not the video streaming? The fact that it is wireless?

Comment: Yes, There is inherit latency with a wireless connection.  If there is a lot of traffic over the wireless connection, if all other users are wireless, then the ping times could caused by that.  Just the inherit design of a wireless connection.

Comment: It seems that the issue is whether you are limited by an overloaded WiFi or limited by an overloaded Comcast connection.  Can you, just temporarily, connect directly to the Comcast modem and see if things run faster?  That would tell you whether bypassing the WiFi would help or not.

Comment: @John1024 I can test it when I'm at home. For sake of simplicity and wiring I'd have to have someone watching video (on a wireless Roku) and run one speedtest / ping on my desktop (wireless) and another one on a laptop next to the modem (wired into the router, not modem, otherwise the point of the exercise which is video streaming would be defeated). That'll be done this evening or night as tonight is busy for me.

Comment: @BunsenBurner Yes, if your modem has only one port, then connect to the router. (Some modern Comcast modems have multiple ports.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look whether your modem supports QoS to set limits on bandwith usage for each user.
Here is a link that should get you going:

http://www.howtogeek.com/75660/the-beginners-guide-to-qos-on-your-router/

Depending on what modem you are using, you could flash it's memory and use Gargoyle or  DD-WRT.

Here's the link to Gargoyle: 
 https://www.gargoyle-router.com/

And this is the link to DD-WRT:
https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service

Comment: Looking into a router replacement which will support Gargoyle, DD-WRT, and (probably) Tomato. Netgear WNDR3700 or WNDR4300

Comment: My current router has QoS (Linksys built in firmware) - I have set the Roku's to low priority based on MAC and my desktop to high priority. It hasn't changed a thing. That's also why I'm looking at a router to flash DD-WRT or something else on is for good / working QoS.

Comment: In my experience, Gargoyle is the most advanced OS. It enables you not only to limit bandwith, but also to limit data (even depending on which user). Here is the link to their shop: http://www.gargoyle-router.com/shop

Comment: You will see better performance from a tool using `pf`, not `iptables`, which is what current releases of Linux use. The FreeBSD-based FOSS project pfSense can do this for you.